# Can this for loop be performed with built in functions?

Tags: python, pandas

This for loop is too slow on large datasets, wondering if it can be written with built in functions to go faster.

The goal here is to create columns AFirst and BFirst, and populate those with 1s and 0s according to the following logic:

- If start = 1, Afirst and Bfirst are equal to 0
- If A >= 2, AFirst = 1
- If B <= -2, BFirst = 1
- Once AFirst or BFirst are equal to 1, all subsequent rows are just duplicates of that row such that before the next start = 1, AFirst or BFirst reflects whichever came first.

.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 'A': {0: 0.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 3.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.5, 7: 1.0, 8: 1.5, 9: 2.0}, 'B': {0: 0.0, 1: -1.0, 2: -1.5, 3: -2.0, 4: -1.0, 5: 0.0, 6: -1.0, 7: -2.0, 8: -3.0, 9: -1.0}})

for i in range(df.shape[0]):

        if df['start'].iloc[i] == 1:

            if (df.loc[df.index[i],'A'] <= 2) & (df.loc[df.index[i],'B'] >= -2):
                df.loc[df.index[i],'AFirst']=0
                df.loc[df.index[i],'BFirst']=0
            elif df.loc[df.index[i],'A'] >= 2:
                df.loc[df.index[i],'AFirst']=1
                df.loc[df.index[i],'BFirst']=0
            elif df.loc[df.index[i],'B'] <= -2:
                df.loc[df.index[i],'AFirst']=0
                df.loc[df.index[i],'BFirst']=1

        elif df.loc[df.index[i-1],'AFirst'] == 1:
            df.loc[df.index[i],'AFirst']=1
            df.loc[df.index[i],'BFirst']=0

        elif df.loc[df.index[i-1],'BFirst'] == 1:
            df.loc[df.index[i],'AFirst']=0
            df.loc[df.index[i],'BFirst']=1

        elif df.loc[df.index[i],'A'] >= 2:
            df.loc[df.index[i],'AFirst']=1
            df.loc[df.index[i],'BFirst']=0

        elif df.loc[df.index[i],'B'] <= -2:
            df.loc[df.index[i],'AFirst']=0
            df.loc[df.index[i],'BFirst']=1
```

Comment: Please don't [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72509649/can-this-for-loop-be-performed-with-built-in-functions) and then repost the same question again. Instead edit your question. What you do here will lead to downvotes.

Comment: @trincot noted.

Comment: Did you mean `A >= 2` or `A <= 2`?

Comment: On line 4, it's A <= 2 or B >=-2 as the purpose here is to not mark the rows 0,0 if A happens to be >=2 or B <=-2 on the same row that start == 1. In all others, A >=2 or B<=-2 is the condition.

Comment: Could you provide a copy of your desired output?

Comment: @BeRT2me if you run the provided code, then df will be the desired output. The code works as intended currently, it's just slow for large datasets

Comment: The `NaN` rows produced are intended then?

Comment: @BeRT2me yes - the only thing that matters to me is that the row above each start == 1 is either [1,0]  , [0,1] , or [NaN,NaN]

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 'A': {0: 0.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 3.0, 4: 4.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.5, 7: 1.0, 8: 1.5, 9: 2.0}, 'B': {0: 0.0, 1: -1.0, 2: -1.5, 3: -2.0, 4: -3.0, 5: 0.0, 6: -1.0, 7: -2.0, 8: -3.0, 9: -4.0}})

# Finds first row from each group that meets the conditions
cond = df[df.A.ge(2) | df.B.le(-2)].groupby(df.start.cumsum(), as_index=False).head(1)

# Sets the correct row to 1, and the other to 0.
cond.loc[cond.A.abs().gt(cond.B.abs()), 'AFirst'] = 1
cond.loc[cond.B.abs().gt(cond.A.abs()), 'BFirst'] = 1
cond = cond.fillna(0)

# Merges the subset we've been working with to the dataframe.
df = df.merge(cond, 'left')

# Fills in 0s to the start rows where they haven't already been filled.
cond = df.start.eq(1)
df[cond] = df[cond].fillna({'AFirst':0,'BFirst':0})

# Front-Fills all values.
df = df.ffill()

# Corrects the front-fills where it filled 0's before we found a one.
df.loc[df[df[['AFirst', 'BFirst']].shift().eq(0).all(axis=1)].groupby(df.start.cumsum(), as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1]).reset_index(-2, drop=True).index, ['AFirst', 'BFirst']] = np.nan
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   start    A    B  AFirst  BFirst
0      1  0.0  0.0     0.0     0.0
1      0  1.0 -1.0     NaN     NaN
2      0  2.0 -1.5     1.0     0.0
3      0  3.0 -2.0     1.0     0.0
4      0  4.0 -3.0     1.0     0.0
5      1  0.0  0.0     0.0     0.0
6      0  0.5 -1.0     NaN     NaN
7      0  1.0 -2.0     0.0     1.0
8      0  1.5 -3.0     0.0     1.0
9      0  2.0 -4.0     0.0     1.0
```

Comment: Thank you - my only concern with this solution is that it does not work in scenarios were A decreases after increasing. I have edited the original question with an updated dataframe showing a situation where this would provide 0,0 instead of 1,0 at index 4

Comment: I think that can be solved by replacing the last 3 lines with the following:

df = df.ffill()
print(df)

Does that look right to you?

Comment: @batataman re-did some of my logic to better apply to any situation, and commented out the steps~

Comment: Thank you - much appreciated. This is ~122x faster than the code I had